# Setting lock mode in informix to wait before executing query

Tags: vb.net, informix

In my vb application i have a query that updates one column in a table. 
But because of the fact that the property for this database lock mode is

`SET LOCK MODE TO NOT WAIT`

sometimes when running query with update I get errors like this:

```
SQL ERR: EIX000: (-144) ISAM error: key value locked
EIX000: (-245) Could not position within a file via an index. (informix.table1)
```

My question is , is it safe to execute:

```
1st SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT;

 2nd the update query;

 3rd SET LOCK MODE TO NOT WAIT;
```

Or you can point me to other solution if this is not safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "safe" to do the three operations as suggested, but …

- Your application may block for an indefinite time while the operation runs.
- If you terminate the query somehow but don't reset the lock mode, other parts of your code may get hung on locks unexpectedly.

Consider whether a wait with timeout is appropriate.

Each thread, if there are threads, should have exclusive access to one connection for the duration of the three operations.